# Hide collapse navbar after link click, react-redux, react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm beginner in react, so, need your help.
I used collapsible bootstrap navbar, have no ideas how to make it collapse after link click on mobile. Native bootsrap property collapseOnSelect not working, or i did something wrong.

```
const  AppBar = () => (
  <Navbar collapseOnSelect>
    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <div className="logo-wrap"> 
          <Link to="define"> 
            <img height='50' src='./../assets/img/logo.png' className="logo"/> 
          </Link> 
        </div> 
      </Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle />
    </Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Collapse>
      <Nav>
        <LinkContainer to="define" className="nav-link"><NavItem eventKey={1}>Home</NavItem></LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="about" className="nav-link"><NavItem eventKey={1}>About</NavItem></LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="features" className="nav-link"><NavItem eventKey={1}>Features</NavItem></LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="pricing" className="nav-link"><NavItem eventKey={1}>Pricing</NavItem></LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="areaMap" className="nav-link"><NavItem eventKey={1}>Area Map</NavItem></LinkContainer>
      </Nav>
      <Nav pullRight>        
        <LinkContainer to="login" className="nav-link"><NavItem eventKey={2}>Log In</NavItem></LinkContainer>
        <LinkContainer to="registration"><NavItem eventKey={2}><Button className="sign-up">Sign Up</Button></NavItem></LinkContainer>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
);


export default AppBar;
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you manage to fix it for your?

Comment: we made a navigation without bootstrap

Comment: Bit late to the party but the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452695/react-bootstrap-how-to-collapse-menu-when-item-is-selected should fix it

Answer (score 5):

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
```

Second in the **Navbar** we add this prop:

```
<Navbar expanded={expanded}>
```

Third, we add an onClick event to the toggle handler that changes the menu visibility status:

```
<Navbar.Toggle onClick={() => setExpanded(expanded ? false : "expanded")} />
```

Fourth we add the prop

```
<Link to="/" onClick={() => setExpanded(false)}>Menu</Link>
```